# Gaussian Algorithm

Tags: calculus

So here's what it looks like:

x1   x2  x3  b
1    1   1   10
4    2   1   16
9    3   1   18

I understand that I'm supposed to have eliminate the 9 and 3 from the last row and the 4 from the second row to get one variable in the last row, two in the second last and so on, but I'm being unable to maintain a 0 in place of 9 when trying to eliminate 3 and vice versa. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Perform Gaussian Elimination on the following augmented matrix.

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 & 10 \\ 4 & 2 & 1 & 16 \\ 9 & 3 & 1 & 18 \end{bmatrix}$$

Follow these row-reduction steps one at a time ($R_x$ = row number, so $R_2: R_2 - 4/9 ~R_1$ means replace $R_2$ by $R_2 - 4/9 \times R_1$ ).

- Swap $R_1$ and $R_3$
- $R_2: R_2 - 4/9 ~R_1$
- $R_2: 9~R_2$
- $R3: R_3 - 1/9 R_1$
- $R_3: 9/2 ~ R_3$
- $R_3: R_2 - 1/2~R_2$
- $R_3: 2/3 ~ R_3$
- $R_2: R_2 - 5~R_2$
- $R_1: R_1 - R_3$
- $R_2: R_2 / 6$
- $R_1: R_1 - 3~R_2$
- $R_1: R_1 / 9$

This gives us the RREF augmented matrix of:

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & -2 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 12 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

Thus, our solution is:

$$x_3 = 0, x_2 = 12, x_1 = -2$$

Comment: Yikes, all those row operations! Deserves a TU! +1

Comment: Yes, it sure did. Thank you! :)